# Any way to track speed of hand movements below iPhone 3.2?

Tags: iphone, cocoa

I have used the pan gesture for tracking the Pixel-Per-Second (or speed of the movement of the hand) but the real trouble is that the PanGesture library doesn't support any deployment target less than 3.2.

So how would I track the speed of hand movements below a deployment target of 3.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HI Friends
 I Got The Perfect Answer From The Following Link

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5075291/i-want-to-track-the-speed-of-the-fingure-movement-in-pixel-per-second-is-it-possi/5083653#5083653